# forward backward algorithm pseudocode clarification

Tags: machine-learning, hidden-markov-models

I had a question regarding the pseudocode on the wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward%E2%80%93backward_algorithm#Python_example) for the forward backward algorithm. Specifically,what is the purpose of this section of code:

## merging the two parts

```
posterior = []
for i in range(L):
    posterior.append({st: fwd[i][st]*bkw[i][st]/p_fwd for st in states})
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late.
The goal of this algorithm is to inference on data given the model. By this calculation you are calculating the posterior probability of P(x_i|o_i) which can help finding out the next step in the test procedure.

Hope that has helped.